# Get primitive root of 1024 bit prime number in sage

Tags: primitive-roots, sagemath

How to find the primitive root of a 1024 bit prime number in sage?
primitive_root(p) takes forever to calculate.

Comment: This is quite difficult unless you know the prime factorisation of $p-1$.